# xlsx writer does not save large files

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, xlsxwriter

I'm parsing a website and creating an xlsx file using selenium + xlsxwriter (in python). I successfully save a regular xlsx, which weighs 28-35 kb, but when the file weighs more (I can't find the border when it's small and when it's a lot), usually the file weighs about 50 kb, the document simply isn't saved, there are no errors in the debugger.

help please

Comment: XlsxWriter can generate very large files. I've generated files larger than 4GB in testing. What environment are you using?

Comment: I using pycharm

Comment: the full path has > 256 characters, so this was a problem.